# What is close reading?

Tags: terminology, close-reading

What exactly is "close reading"? How does it relate to the study of literature? Are there any instructions about how to do a close reading of a text/passage?

Comment: Some context would be nice.

Comment: Perhaps you should do a self-answer for this question citing your ["Naming of Parts" Q&A](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2782/17), so that we can point people at this post to tell them what close reading is rather than at one where the *question* doesn't even mention close reading.

Comment: @Randal'Thor if you want to, go ahead. But any answer that I write here will probably just quote a definition of close reading, say that you need to learn by doing, and then link to my naming of parts q&a. Writing an answer here doesn't seem like a productive use of my time tbh.

Answer (score 5):

> In literary criticism, close reading is the careful, sustained
>   interpretation of a brief passage of a text. A close reading
>   emphasizes the single and the particular over the general, effected by
>   close attention to individual words, the syntax, and the order in
>   which the sentences unfold ideas, as the reader scans the line of
>   text.

— [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Close_reading)

> Close reading expects readers to focus on the information that a text
>   provides, without relying on a lot of information or support. This is
>   different from other kinds of reading lessons you teach, in which you
>   may start out by introducing teacher-set purposes, discussions of
>   students’ life experiences, picture walks, and so on.
>
> Close reading discourages such front-loading. The goal of close
>   reading instruction is to foster independent readers who are able to
>   plumb the depths of a text by considering only the text itself.
>
> We all know that it’s not enough to just understand what a text says.
>   Close readers not only grasp an author’s message, but they also take a
>   look under the hood, so to speak. They try to recognize the author’s
>   tone or perspective, the implications of the author’s word choices,
>   and why a text is structured or organized as it is. Additionally,
>   readers should go beyond a text, evaluating its quality or value,
>   comparing it with other texts, or determining its implications. It’s a
>   lot to ask of students, but with appropriate scaffolding and support,
>   they can do it.

— [Scholastic](https://www.scholastic.com/teachers/articles/teaching-content/common-core-close-reading-0/)

I think that means that when doing a close reading one examines writing by moving slowly through the text, examining very small distinctions such as the choice of a single word.

Comment: So, is it mostly about reading between the lines, concentrating on word choice, and stripping away the context?

Comment: @LauraCookson Hi. I think close reading is best learned through examples. I just posted an example of close reading on this site that will walk you through the process of conducting a close reading. Hope you find it helpful. https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/2782/why-does-the-poem-naming-of-parts-contrast-war-with-nature